# Groovy in android - launcher activity cant be found

Tags: java, android, groovy

i'm trying to run a simple android program.  The issue is the launcher activity is a groovy file, it's called MainActivity.groovy and it resides in the java source folder.  Here is a photo of my gradle dependencies and project structure:

[image]

and here is the android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and lastly here is the error when i run the program:

```
07-08 17:11:49.297  20173-20173/com.example.uen229.myrxjavaandroidproject2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.uen229.myrxjavaandroidproject2, PID: 20173
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uen229.myrxjavaandroidproject2/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.uen229.myrxjavaandroidproject2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.uen229.myrxjavaandroidproject2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MainActivity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

i have tried restarting my pc and IDE. Keep in mind the MainActivity has been renamed to MainActivity.groovy.  What am i doing wrong ?

UPDATE: After following the instructions [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin)

i made my directory structure looked like the following which resolved the issue:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `src/main/groovy`?

Comment: Also, make sure you've added the plugin to the build.gradle file : https://github.com/karfunkel/grooid-playground/blob/master/app1/build.gradle

Comment: Are you using the Android Groovy plugin?

Comment: thanks tim_yates your link is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have many problems:

- Groovy files should be under `groovy` folder, not `java`
- Android does not support groovy as a native language, just java, so you need to pre-compile the groovy files in order to let the Dalvik/ART execute it. The way to do so is applying a plugin in the build.gradle that does this work for you.

[This](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin) is a great tutorial for the plugin on github.

Comment: thanks i followed this instructions and got it going https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin.

Comment: I will add this link to the answer.