# groovy error - cannot find matching method - how to solve

Tags: android, groovy

I have a simple activity in android but it could be any class. anyway it looks like this:

```
package com.example.groovy
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
import com.example.R
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myMethod();
    }




    public void myMethod(){

        Data data1=new Data();


        data1.setAddress("37 IBM blvd.");
        data1.setPostalCode("mc42L8")
        data1.setDate("feb 19");

        Data data2=new Data();
        data2.setAddress("38 Oriole");
        data2.setPostalCode("mc72l9")
        data2.setDate("feb 12");

        Data data3=new Data();
        data3.setAddress("37 skyway");
        data3.setPostalCode("mt82l9");
        data3.setDate("feb 13");
}
```

The Data class looks like this:

```
package com.example.groovy

public class Data{
    def String address
    def String postalCode
    def String Date
}
```

if you need to know the directory structure it looks like this:

[image]
here is the error i get when i try to run the program:

```
    /Users/frost/Documents/myandroidstudio/myrxJavaAndroidProject2/app/src/main/groovy/com/example/groovy/MainActivity.groovy: 32: [Static type checking] - 
Cannot find matching method com.example.groovy.Data#setDate(java.lang.String). 

Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
```

this error repeats for all the synthesized methods im trying to access from the data pojo.

Comment: You just asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304037/groovy-in-android-launcher-activity-cant-be-found.

Comment: no, this question is about the class not being synthesized its differerent.  This time im not able to pick up the methods from the Data class. Can you suggestion  something ?

Comment: Why dont you start with a sample application and build up from there?

Comment: Hey Jared, thats exactly what i did. This is basically a hello world application which runs fine. Its just when i try to access the Data class's synthezied methods that it fails. If you comment out the entire myMethod(), then the program builds and runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with sensible capitalisation, and without unnecessary `def`s?

```
public class Data{
    String address
    String postalCode
    String date
}
```

Comment: the date variable i had as a capital. that seemed to cause the issue. very strange, thanks for the advice.